# Why I'm getting "This app is incompatible with your device for all devices" on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, build.gradle

We have android app which is giving **This app is incompatible with your device.** for all devices which are trying to access the app listing on Google Play Store.

**While Developing** The app is working and can be installed freely on any device but from play store it is not getting installed.

Attaching gradle file where I feel the error is coming!

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a' // i believe this is this the issue (before judging please read the p.s)
        universalApk true
   }
}

defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 
        targetSdkVersion 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86_64','arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a' // i believe this is this the issue (before judging please read the p.s)
        }
    }
```

When I created the apk, I'm getting just one APK which i'm uploading to the google play console

**Phones used while development** Xiaomi and Samsung and all of them have Android Version 8, 9, 10

**P.s** I'm a fullstack developer, my company has given me responsibility of managing android app development also, now developers are developing the application under me, and i'm just responsible for releasing the application to play store. And when I asked them, they are not aware of this issue as they are freshers

Comment: Did you try analyzing the release apk and find if there are any libraries that are not compatible with 64-bit? Because i recieved a similar issue some time ago and removing a library that was 32-bit only solved my problem

Comment: @hamzakhan how can i do that ?

Comment: Build a release apk and then you get the option to locate, analyze apk . From there analyze the apk.

Comment: @hamzakhan now what is the next step, how can I analyze it ?

Comment: can you post the ss of the analyze apk popup?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solutions, I don't remember how I came to this conclusion

In the manifest file, inside **defaultConfig** object and inside ndk, I added **'x86'** which fixed the issue and now app is compatible with devices

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion 
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        // ***************** check this line for the answer *****************

        abiFilters 'x86_64','arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' // <------ Added 'x86'

        // ***************** check the above line for answer ****************
    }
}
```